# How to remove default value from input number in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I have a Vue input number component which accepts precision upto five decimal points. Its all fine except it shows the default value 0.000000 which is kinda boring to look at because this field is optional. I am using el-input-number component from the `element-ui`. Is there any tweak to remove the boring default value of `0.000000` ?

```
<span class="custom-label">
Optional Multiplier Amount
</span>
<el-input-number
   :controls="false"
   v-model="form.multiplier_amount"
   :size="size"
   :step="0.1"
   :precision="5"
   class="optional-multiplier"
   />

data(){
 return{
  form: {
    multiplier_amount: null
        }
       }
      }
```

[image]

Comment: if `placeholder="..."` doesn't work add a ref to access the element (or traverse through it to the input) to change the placeholder

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thats not because of placeholder

Comment: You could maybe have `multiplier_amount: 0.00000 || ''` in your `data()`/`computed()`.

Comment: oh right so `form.multiplier_amount = 0.00000`? then its obvious, remove the value :/

Comment: @kissu my data value is null, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set it as `undefined`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data(){
    return{
      form: {
        multiplier_amount: undefined
      },
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <span class="custom-label">
    Optional Multiplier Amount
  </span>
  <el-input-number
    :controls="false"
    v-model="form.multiplier_amount"
    :step="0.1"
    class="optional-multiplier"
    :precision="5"
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still if you run your example it will have a default value of 0, which is exactly what I wanted to remove. 0.00000 or 0 is same thing, I just need to force users to have max 5 points. So it still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @gitam gadtaula hey mate, take a look again I corrected my answer

Comment: Thanks it works. By the way is it possible that having the default value as undefined may bring unprecedented complication in the future ? What might be the effect of using undefined over null ?

Comment: In your context no worries I think :)